# Excel formula to replace first occurrence of a character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to excel, I have a data of 1000 rows with each row looks like `435362|A|B|C` I want a formula in excel which modifies each rows so that the data looks like `435362,A|B|C` i.e. it should replace first occurrence of | with comma(,).

Answer (score 13):

One more option: (with data in `A1`):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",",",1)
```

You can't replace existing data with forrmula, so you need to create another column. You can then cut and paste as values to replace existing data.

Comment: But this will do one at a time right. How to do for 1000 rows at once

Comment: @rampuriyaaa if you enter the above formula in the first cell next to your column of data, you can then drag it down to row 1000 (using a small square in bottom right corner of cell selection rectangle). If you double click that square it should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND("|",A1)-1) & "," & MID(A1,FIND("|",A1)+1,9999)
```

and copy down

Answer (score 0):

If every string in all 1000 rows is the same length, this should do the trick:

=REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-5,1,",")

Explanations:

1. The two instances of "A1" in the formula are the cell references, these would need to change for each cell in order to work, but if you copy the formula across cells this value should change automatically.
2. The LEN is finding the length of the string in the cell, then the -5 is finding the symbol 5th from the end (in this case the "|"). The 1 is saying only replace this one symbol (2 would replace "|" and "A"), and the "," is telling the formula which symbol to replace the "|" with".

I hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

If your data have the same char length the you can use  `=CONCATENATE(LEFT(B3,6),",",RIGHT(B3,5))` B3 is where your data is located in this case. 
This is only one way of doing it.